# Advertising Id Google Play Policy?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

HI guys I am using Admob Ads in my app , do i have to declare this permission in manifest if i dont need Advertising Id...

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

[image]

Comment: The permission is already declared in Admob library, so you'll find it in the merged manifest file even if you do not declare it.
You could strip it by declaring <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove" />, and this should prevent the usage of the Ad ID starting from Android 13. I am not sure which will be the correct answer to that question in this case, as it will be still used on previous Android versions.